# Is it possible to serialize a SwiftUI view (i.e. not the ViewModel/state info, but the actual view itself)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Does Apple provide any way to serialize/deserialize a SwiftUI view for persistence reasons? To be clear, I mean the views themselves, not the data used to build them. I know Apple doesn't give us access to the view tree/hierarchy itself, which makes sense because they aren't 'objects' in a hierarchy, but there are view types, each with state, so I'm wondering if that can somehow be captured/persisted then recreated.

I'm asking because we're trying to mirror/mimic a similar concept in Windows WPF applications where you can serialize/deserialize entire UI elements into what's known as XAML, or Extensible Application Markup Language which is an XML format.  You can store that data in say, a database, then reload it at runtime, rehydrating an entire UI, including bindings to data.  While we don't need anything that elaborate--we just need loading static views--I'm not finding *anything* on this topic.

Now I know I could write my own 'builder' classes that look for types that I define from known 'model' types, then dynamically build up those views accordingly, but that would require writing an entire engine just for that limited purpose. So... is there any such thing already out there, or is this just not possible by design?

Comment: SwiftUI view, actually, is a function, so there is nothing to serialize... you really only need to serialize view model.

Comment: Yes, but can you capture the results of that function, then re-present it kind of thing.  For instance, I know I can use a view model to connect to a checkbox view, but the view model would only have a boolean value. I'm looking for something that actually caches that it's a checkbox too.  Make sense?

Comment: Are you referring to State Restoration with SwifUI? If so refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui

Comment: No, I was referring to entire view serialization, meaning you could serialize the definition of the view itself, then restore elsewhere.  Doesn't look like this is possible with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can serialize a SwiftUI view. Just conform to the Codable protocol and you are good to go. Here is a small example:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View, Codable {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())


let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(ContentView())
print(data)

let contentView = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ContentView.self, from: data!)
print(contentView)
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't quite do what I want. For instance, if you look at the resulting JSON here, it's on'y `{}` because there's no 'properties' on the view to serialize.  Makes sense though... JSON serialization doesn't serialize type information like XAML does.    Still, I think this is the best we're gonna get. If no one else comes up with something different in the next few days, I'll mark this as the answer.